# How to convert the related model data to Array while getting parent model data from real database?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have a schema in realm db where data comes from different models to parent model.

I am able to convert the data I get from parent model to Array by doing

```
static get() {
    let result = realm.objects(this.schema.name)
    return result.map(x => Object.assign({}, x))
}
```

Here is sample the data inside parent model,

```
[
{"deal_id":"d001","product_id":"p001",
"user_defined_attributes":{"0":{"name":"Color","value":"Red"},"1":{"name":"Quality","value":"NO.1"}},
"deal_channels":{"0":{"channel_id":"d001_u00001_u00002","to_user_id":"u00002","deal_id":"d001",
"chat_messages":{"0":{"message_id":"m1","channel_id":"d001_u00001_u00002","time_stamp":1533548036,"sendor_id":"u00001","storage_status":"active","status":"seen"}}}}
]
```

How can I convert the data in 'user_defined_attributes', 'deal_channels' and then data in 'chat_messages' to Array.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the given JSON object using below code.

```
var obj =  obj[0];
var convert = (o) => Object.keys(o).map(k => o[k]);
obj.user_defined_attributes = convert(obj.user_defined_attributes)
obj.deal_channels = convert(obj.deal_channels).map(d => {
   d.chat_messages = convert(d.chat_messages);
   return d;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but I have huge number of models and I can't do it manually